# Trackball Controls taking over the screen

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to add a basic trackball control to my THREE.JS scene, however, when I do so, it takes control of my whole screen. I cannot right click on anything in the screen or click into any textboxes.

Comment: The usual solution is `controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @WestLangley When I do this, I have no control over the scene at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your own changes if you want to change that behaviour, these event methods prevent default behaviour:

```
function mousedown( event ) {

    if ( _this.enabled === false ) return;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
```